# Why are "Domain Users" are member of "Domain Admins" group?

Tags: security, windows-server, windows-domain, windows-server-2019, domain-security

I'm new to Windows Server administration. Recently I created a home network and chose one of my computers as domain controller. It is a Windows Server 2019.

On that server, I noticed "Domain Users" are member of "Domain Admins" group. Does it mean whoever joins to domain will be member of "Domain Admins" ? If the answer is Yes, it means all users connected to domain have full access to do anything?

[image]

Comment: yes that is more or less correct. this is not a wise configuration unless all users are experienced server admins, and even then.... instead of saying they have access to everything, its probably safer to say there is nothing they cannot give themselves access to.

Comment: I believe it's the default setting. I don't recall doing such a thing. Any thought?

Comment: That is most definitely not a default setting.

Comment: Thank you for information.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the default group membership. Some one has added Domain User group to Domain Admins. This effectively grants ever domain user full administrator rights on all domain computers and users. That is very bad.